# How to set a max message size in ActiveMq

Tags: activemq-classic

I am working with ActiveMQ (5.15.2) and have the following question. Is there any way for me to impose a maximum size for messages? Can I set this limitation for a given queue/topic (so topic A has a 1k message limitation and topic B has a 5k message limitation)?
Also, is it possible to set this limitation for a given connection?
I have searched around and cant't find anything out-of-the-box. It seems like the only way would be to define custom plugins.

Is there any out of the box way that I am now aware of? And, if not, can anyone point me to what would be the best way to define such a limitation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To set the max message size (32k in the example below) for all messages on a specific transport connector, set the wireformat.maxFrameSize value (in bytes)

```
<transportConnector .. uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?wireformat.maxFrameSize=32768.."
```

ref: [Configure transport wireformat settings](https://activemq.apache.org/configuring-wire-formats.html)

Comment: Add'l questions asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69099212/how-to-set-the-apache-mq-topic-size-and-time-to-live-and-restart-active-mq-progr