# How to set the Apache MQ topic size and time to live and restart active MQ programmatically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I am new to Apache ActiveMQ. I want to set the number of messages allowed in a topic and the time to live (ttl) of the messages depending on the choice the user makes from the UI. If the user makes a change then restart the ActiveMQ with updated ttl and topic size.

Could someone please let me know how to do this programmatically in Java?

As of now, I have understood that altering the `constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy` in the `activemq.xml` file (attached below for reference) by using dom parser in Java will help define the topic size at any given point of time. However, I do not know how to alter "time to live" according to our preference.

```xml
<beans
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">


        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true">
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
        -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage limit="64 mb"/>
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please see [ask], to meet the level of detail required in a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @OlafKock Thank you for your suggestion. I have now updated the description with more details.

Comment: @JustinBertram By message topic size, I mean the number of messages that must be present in the topic at any given point of time